# Descending order table as well as Ascending in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

so I've created a dynamic JavaScript table which works with HTML to create a Miles to KM converter.  My table currently runs Ascending order, but am unsure on how to make it run Descending as the user should have the option.  I'm fairly convinced it is to so with the for loop but I was wondering if someone could help me out with this.

```
function milesConverterAsc(tagId, from, to){

var first = document.getElementById("Input1");
var second = document.getElementById("Input2");
from = parseInt(first.value);
to = parseInt(second.value);
var conv = document.getElementById(tagId);
var tab = document.createElement("table");
var bod = document.createElement("tbody");
var thed = document.createElement("thead");
tab.appendChild(thed);
tab.appendChild(bod);
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
thed.appendChild(tr);
var th = document.createElement("th");
tr.appendChild(th);
th.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Miles"));
th = document.createElement("th");
tr.appendChild(th);
th.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Kilometers"));
conv.appendChild(tab);

for(var i=from; i<=to; i++){
    tr = document.createElement("tr");
    if (i <= -1){
        alert("Value must be positive Integer");
        return false;
    }
    else if (i % 2 == 0)
        tr.setAttribute("class", "even");
    else
        tr.setAttribute("class", "odd");
    bod.appendChild(tr);
    td = document.createElement("td");
    tr.appendChild(td);
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
    td = document.createElement("td");
    tr.appendChild(td);
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(mtk(i)));
}
function mtk(m) {
    outputOne = ((m * 1.6093)*10)/10;
    outputTwo = outputOne.toFixed(2);
    return outputTwo
}
```

EDIT: Here is the HTML code I am using in order to get the inputs.

```
<form action="">
<p> ASCENDING ORDER</p>
</br></br>
    <textarea rows="1" name="Input1" id="Input1" cols="10"></textarea>
    <textarea rows="1" name="Input2" id="Input2" cols="10"></textarea>

</form>
```

Hopefully you can help me out! This is the ascending code.

Comment: Can you include the html you are using as well for inputs

Comment: @PeteTalksWeb Sure, done now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create your table rows in the for loop. Each row is based on the index variable of that for loop. Right now it will always be in ascending order, assuming from < to. To make it reverse it's order, just switch your for loop setup to:

```
for(var i=to; i>=from; i--)
```

[A simple codepen to demonstrate](http://A%20simple%20codepen%20to%20demonstrate)

Comment: Thank you, this works! Really appreciate it.  I knew it could be to do with the loop, didn't think to do i-- instead of i++.